# Using ReplayKit & HTTPStream and cast to Chromecast

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, chromecast

I need to use Replaykit (Broadcast extension UI) to be able to cast content from iPhone to TV (Chrome cast).
Currently I am using Haishinkit library, I have written content to HTTPStream (CMSampleBuffer), I use this URL and cast to TV, it doesn't work.

```
        let url = URL.init(string: "abc.m38u")!
        let mediaInfoBuilder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder.init(contentURL: url)
        mediaInfoBuilder.streamType = GCKMediaStreamType.buffered
        mediaInfoBuilder.contentID = mediaURL.absoluteString
        mediaInfoBuilder.contentType = mediaURL.mimeType()
        mediaInfoBuilder.hlsSegmentFormat = .TS
        mediaInfoBuilder.hlsVideoSegmentFormat = .MPEG2_TS
        mediaInfoBuilder.streamDuration = .infinity
```

Where am I going wrong.

Can I use any other way to stream content to Chromecast, because using HTTPStream, the content is deleyed for about 5 to 10 seconds.
Thanks.

Comment: By it doesn't work, what do you expect to happen, and are there any error messages?

Comment: It's not show error message.  The Cast SDK makes an attempt at loading the media, but ultimately fails without errors (resulting in just the black screen with the Cast logo)